# Compilation error in using boost serialization for stl containers with non-copyable values

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-serialization

If I have a non-copyable class and use this class as a value type of a stl container that I wanted to serialize it using boost serialize I get a compile error which indicates that I had wanted to use a deleted function. A simple code that causes the error is like this:

```
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{                                                                                                                                                                                
public:
  string s;

  Foo()
  {}

  Foo(string s):
    s(s)
  {}


  Foo(const Foo& other) = delete;
  Foo &operator=(const Foo &other) = delete;

  Foo(Foo &&other) noexcept = default;
  Foo &operator=(Foo &&other) noexcept = default;



  template <typename Archive>
  void save(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) const
  {
    ar & this->s;
  }

  template <typename Archive>
  void load(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & this->s;
  }

  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()

  friend class boost::serialization::access;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  vector<pair<const uint8_t, Foo>> bar;

  const char* text_file_name = "/tmp/test-fixed-multibit.txt";
  {
    std::ofstream ofs(text_file_name);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);
    ar & bar;
  }

  {
    vector<pair<const uint8_t, Foo>> bar1;

    std::ifstream ifs(text_file_name);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ar(ifs);

    ar & bar1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Which it gives me an error like this:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = const unsigned char; _T2 = Foo]’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:60,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/serialization/vector.hpp:20,
                 from foo.cc:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:128:17: note: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = const unsigned char; _T2 = Foo]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
       constexpr pair(pair&&) = default;
                 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:128:17: error: use of deleted function ‘Foo::Foo(const Foo&)’
foo.cc:28:3: error: declared here
   Foo(const Foo& other) = delete;
```

I deleted some parts of the error, but they were like lines we have copied here. You can check the correctness of the code by replacing `Foo` with another type like `string`.

Do I have a mistake about using boost or is this a misbehavior of boost serialize?

I used c++11 with g++-4.8 and my boost version is 1-60.0 compiled from source.

**Edit:**

As @sehe stated in his answer using g++-5.x can solve the compile error. But it is true just for `std::vector` and using other containers like `std::unordered_map` causes the same compile error even with g++-5.x.

Comment: The value type of std::vector should be at least movable.

Comment: No It does not. You can compile this code without a problem without serialization (at least if you use no-except for move constructor) because `vector` can use move constructor. And this is just an example you can check this for another containers of stl such as `map` or `unordered_map`.

Comment: Sorry I did not get your comment. This class has move constructor. because it implicitly is generated.

Comment: "This class has move constructor". Try adding one explicitly `Foo(Foo&&) = default; Foo& operator= (Foo&&) = default;` and see what happens.

Comment: I added this two lines `Foo(Foo &&other) noexcept = default;` and 
`Foo &operator=(Foo &&other) noexcept = default;` but still I get this error.

Comment: It looks like a bug in Boost. They are using vector::push_back() from a lvalue reference. This seems to require a copy constructor.

Comment: But it is the same for the other containers, so it may be the general error of boost serialization.

Comment: Other containers have their own copying insertion. But you should ask yourself what it means to serialize a non-copyable thing. If you serialize and then deserialize one, wouldn't you effectively create a copy?

Comment: I think serializing is not related to copying an object. Because by deserializing I am creating another object which may not exist before it.

Comment: Serialization is different from copying but copying seema to be easily implementable in terms of serialization. If you have serialization, why disallow copying?

Comment: Yes it may be possible. But I have a flood of pointers that points to each others, management of those is a responsibility of boost serialize. If I want to do this manually many unnecessary overheads add to my code and it also has no usage in my code just can cause some mistake in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bug in boost code, I reported [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11961) in boost bug tracker. But for a fast solution you could change one line in file `boost/serialization/archive_input_unordered_map.hpp` line 43 (`s.insert(t.reference());`) must be replaced with:

```
  s.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(t.reference().first)),
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(t.reference().second)));
```

This is for boost-1.60 and you must find the line in other versions, and it just corrects unordered_map insertion. May be general solution possible for that but currently this patch solved my problem.

**Update:**

As in the [bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11961) have reported, this bug has fixed in boost-1.61.

Answer (score 1):

The problems seems to be that `std::string` is not `noexcept` move-assignable:

```
  // PR 58265, this should be noexcept.
  // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
  // 2063. Contradictory requirements for string move assignment
```

(that's from line 584 in my basic_string.h)

Indeed replacing `std::string` with `int` make everything work fine:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fffb2b44105a61b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Foo {
    int s;

    Foo(int s = {}) : s(s) {}

    Foo(const Foo &other) = delete;
    Foo &operator=(const Foo &other) = delete;

    Foo(Foo &&other) noexcept = default;
    Foo &operator=(Foo &&other) noexcept = default;

    template <typename Archive> void save(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) const { ar & this->s; }

    template <typename Archive> void load(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) { ar & this->s; }

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::pair<const uint8_t, Foo> > bar;

    const char *text_file_name = "test-fixed-multibit.txt";
    {
        std::ofstream ofs(text_file_name);
        boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);
        ar & bar;
    }

    {
        std::vector<std::pair<const uint8_t, Foo> > bar1;

        std::ifstream ifs(text_file_name);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ar(ifs);

        ar & bar1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that gcc 5.x doesn't have much trouble with it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ff6eba4386d940f

Comment: I think the problem is from g++-4.x because even with `int` it could not be compiled with those versions of compiler. May be the reason of compilation error was not about `noexcept` keyword top.

Comment: I based my analysis in part on the errors diagnosed by clang, but only when using GNU'S libstdc++

Comment: Also I found that using `g++-5.x` just corrects the vector version, but other containers like `unordered_map` still gives the same error.